# Is there a reliable version of iAd for android?

Tags: android, ios, iad

I've done a bit of research including on here and haven't found any concrete answers. The gist of what i've gotten is iAd is good for iOS, but isn't available for android. Alternatively, ADMOB is available for all systems, but gives you virtually no return on the ads. Many have said that it's not even worth having ads if you use ADMOB for how low the return rate is.

Essentially, is there a good program like iAd for android that gives worthwhile returns?

Comment: iAd is Apple's network, so, no it is not available on Android.  There are hundreds of different mobile ad network companies out there, and returns will vary greatly depending on a wide variety of factors.  You will need to either sit through all their sales pitches (just send an e-mail and you'll never get rid of them) and make a guess on your own, or hire someone who has experience with them, or just try different ones until you are satisfied.

Comment: I don't have any experience with iAd but my experience with AdMob is that it generates ( roughly ) 5 dollars a day / 1000 active users . Your own experience will be all over the place depending on your app category.